# why we turned to access superclass members although we can inherit them?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

if we have 2 class Zoo & Moo as follows:

```
public class zoo {
    String superString="super";
    private String coolMethod(){
        return "Zoo method";
    }
}

public class Moo extends zoo{
    public void useMyCoolMethod(){
        zoo z=new zoo();
        System.out.println(superString);//1
        System.out.println(z.superString);//2
    }
    public  static void main(String[]args){
        new Moo().useMyCoolMethod();
    }
}
```

at 1 & 2 we print the value of the String in the super class through inheritance and access, the question is , what is the benefit of Access although i can do the same thing by inheritance ? knowing that the Access approach isn't allowed if the two classes is in diff packages

Comment: I don't know of any benefit apart from *potentially* less code and perhaps more readable (depending upon the person)...if anything, I would say that you do more harm than good with access since you violate the principle of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By accessing through the object ref you are modifying the referenced object's state, by inheritance you are modifying the object you are currently in ( this reference ). So there is actually no benefit aside from encapsulation at class level and package level through out the access modifiers and that sort of thing, you just use it depending on the behavior you want for you're code, or in this case, how restrictive to modify the state of objects depending on the context.

But aside from that, i'm not sure if there is anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your example there is no benefit at all in "access" the method, if you really wants to print  "super" twice.

But normally OO programs contains more than two classes and the authors tries to modularize the code with defined interfaces (aka public methods or an API). Create modules with inheritance only is very hard and create clumsy code. So objects will need other instances and call there method by "access".

Comment: "Zoo method" would never get printed. "super" would get printed twice. coolMethod(), as defined in zoo, is never called.

Answer (score 1):

The access (default or package-private) would be useful if `Moo` was in the same package an didn't extend `Zoo`.

Answer (score 1):

In line 1, you are using inheritance, i.e. you have a class animal and you have method move() which moves the animal using his four leg. But in case of Kangaroo, you want to use most of the feature of animal class but want to change how it moves based on the fact that it jumps and uses it hind leg for movement.

In Line 2, you are using composition, i.e. when you want to create car, you will need different component and they will interact with each other for that car to function. Here you can not inherit from GearBox or Engine but you have to use them as part of Car (or what you are calling access).

In the end its the relationship between Zoo and Moo will decide what method you want to use

Answer (score 1):

Using this access and inheritance is same when you `do Not want to modify the content of the inherited memeber..`

eg:

```
public class A {

    String s = "Hello";

   }

public class B extends A{

    String s = "Hi;

   System.out.println(s);  // Will print the s in class B

   System.out.println(new A().s);  // Will print the s in class A

   }
```

Now as String s has no modifier, it is considered having `Default modifier`, that means it can be accessed by `classes only with in its own package.`

If you use protected access modifier, then you Need to extend the class and then use the inherited members, `but you can Not use the protected member by creating an instance of the class that holds it and then use dot operator to access it, this will Not work..`

eg :

```
package com.go;

public class A {

  protected String s= "Hi";

 }

 package com.fo;

 public class B extends A {

  System.out.println(s);  // This will work

  A a = new A();
  System.out.println(a.s); // This will NOT work

 }
```

Comment: Just FYI `code formatting` is meant for code. Maybe you want to use **bold** instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think is a good practice to maintain class attributes with private visibility, and access them through getters and setters. 
In second place, you are not accessing the attribute by inheritance, you are creating an instance of Zoo, and accessing the superString attribute because of it package visibility, you could also access them from another class of the package that don't even extends Zoo class (and that's generally not a good thing) 
 In third place, you don't need to create an instance of the super class to access his public or default attribute, you could simply do:

```
System.out.println(this.superString)
```

wich is absolutly the same as (if not local variable or parameter declared with the same name):

```
System.out.println(superString)
```

In conclusion, having default or public attributes, let client classes access them (read and write) without the class could do nothing about it, and this could bring side effects for the methods of the class that use those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 you have a separate instance of your zoo object, which is a bit weird, but since the method will always return the same thing there isn't much difference.  If you changed your method to be based on constructor input or something you could see a difference in the 2.

```
public class zoo {
    public String superString;
    public zoo (String _superstring) {
        superString = _superstring;
    }
}

public class Moo extends zoo{
    public void useMyCoolMethod(){
        zoo z=new zoo("string1");
        System.out.println(superString);//1
        System.out.println(z.superString);//2
    }
    public Moo (String _superstring) {
        superString = _superstring;
    }
    public  static void main(String[]args){
        new Moo("string2").useMyCoolMethod();
    }
}
```

Will return

> string2
>   string1